How to release the one of the JTAGs control from vivado
I am running an FPGA with virtual IO in vivado. I am controlling the pins and monitoring the LEDs with virtual IO. I am also using the HS2 Rev A JTAG chip to program the RTL desing over the FPGA pins that I assigned (tck tdo tdi tms). I totally have 3 USB cable connected to computer(1st for vivado programming and vio, 2nd for HS2 Rev.A JTAG debug connection with RTL, 3rd for FPGA UART communication with the RTL design). When I open vivado hardware manager and use the virtual IO, I cannot be able to open openocd connection even though I stated the USB port correctly on the configuration file as adapter usb location 1-5. As I understand, vivado take both JTAG ports too. When I close the vivado, there is no problem on the openocd side. However, I need to keep both open at the same time.
Is this possible?
I use Ubuntu 22.04. I have podman(if this helps). My FPGA is ZCU102
EDIT:
It couldn't be solved in the community forum.
I think this question needs more knowledge on the usb, jtag, linux, and ports to be solved. I know that there is a solution when it happens in windows. The solution is creating a virtual box and giving one USB port to it so that it is like working with two different computer. I wonder if there is a way to make it using different user on my linux desktop or using podman docker containers. Virtual box on my desktop will be the last use-case for me(If I couldn't find any solution)

Is there Xilinx support you can reach out to? Or a community forum?

Yes there is. I read the similar problems but I couldn't find the same problem and the solution for me.

But why don't you ask it yourself? Via either support or a forum?

I thought I can find answer easily here because more people are using here which thought me more change to find a person having similar problem.
